# What happens to my Swap space if I choose to replace Windows with Ubuntu?

Tags: swap

When I install Ubuntu 12.04, I'll be presented with three options:

1. install Ubuntu alongside Windows,
2. replace Windows with Ubuntu and
3. something else.

If I choose 'replace Windows', then I cannot make a swap space. So what then? I've 1GB RAM.

- Will only my C drive get replaced or what will happen?
- If only C drive is affected, then will data on the other 2 drives get saved?
- If yes, how can I access it (on which drive of Ubuntu) after installing Ubuntu?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you choose to 'replace windows` that means the following:

1. Swap will be created automatically with space equal double your RAM size which means you'll have a 2 GB swap space.
2. It will replace the whole disk not only the C partition so you have to take backup of your data before if you want to keep it.

Answer (score 1):

You can always use the manual partitioner(something else) and tune the selections to your preferences. Make sure, however, that on your Linux partition, you set the **mount point** to `/`.

You can click Edit on your Windows partition and decrease its size by half. It is shown in MB. Then, make a swap partition with 2000 to 4000 MB, and mark Use As as Swap. Then, make a new partition with the maximum available size and Use As=Ext4. Mark the box to format it  and make sure the **Mount Point** is set to `/`.

Comment: To add to what @ObsessiveSSOℲ said, here is a video tutorial explaining the process. You can even view it from the live session. :) [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_trEVXBgLg](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=o_trEVXBgLg)